# How to Share a sdcard folder on dropbox in android

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I have successfully shared video in Dropbox, but I want share a video folder from SDcard  into Dropbox. Please help me if there is any solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

```
public class UploadPicture extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {

    private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
    private String mPath;
    private File mFile;

    private long mFileLen;
    private UploadRequest mRequest;
    private Context mContext;
    private final ProgressDialog mDialog;

    private String mErrorMsg;


    public UploadPicture(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath,
            File file) {
        // We set the context this way so we don't accidentally leak activities
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        mFileLen = file.length();
        mApi = api;
        mPath = dropboxPath;
        mFile = file;




        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mDialog.setMax(100);
        mDialog.setMessage("Uploading " + file.getName());
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setProgress(0);
        mDialog.setButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // This will cancel the putFile operation
                mRequest.abort();
            }
        });
        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // By creating a request, we get a handle to the putFile operation,
            // so we can cancel it later if we want to
              System.out.println(mPath);
              System.out.println(mFile); 




            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("mnt/sdcard/aa/ashu1.mp4");
            String path = mPath + mFile.getName();
            mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(),
                    new ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public long progressInterval() {
                    // Update the progress bar every half-second or so
                    return 500;
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                    publishProgress(bytes);
                }
            });

            if (mRequest != null) {
                mRequest.upload();
                return true;
            }

        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            // This session wasn't authenticated properly or user unlinked
            mErrorMsg = "This app wasn't authenticated properly.";
        } catch (DropboxFileSizeException e) {
            // File size too big to upload via the API
            mErrorMsg = "This file is too big to upload";
        } catch (DropboxPartialFileException e) {
            // We canceled the operation
            mErrorMsg = "Upload canceled";
        } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
            // Server-side exception.  These are examples of what could happen,
            // but we don't do anything special with them here.
            if (e.error == DropboxServerException._401_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                // Unauthorized, so we should unlink them.  You may want to
                // automatically log the user out in this case.
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._403_FORBIDDEN) {
                // Not allowed to access this
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._404_NOT_FOUND) {
                // path not found (or if it was the thumbnail, can't be
                // thumbnailed)
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE) {
                // user is over quota
            } else {
                // Something else
            }
            // This gets the Dropbox error, translated into the user's language
            mErrorMsg = e.body.userError;
            if (mErrorMsg == null) {
                mErrorMsg = e.body.error;
            }
        } catch (DropboxIOException e) {
            // Happens all the time, probably want to retry automatically.
            mErrorMsg = "Successful image Loading.";
        } catch (DropboxParseException e) {
            // Probably due to Dropbox server restarting, should retry
            mErrorMsg = "Dropbox error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            // Unknown error
            mErrorMsg = "Unknown error.  Try again.";
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
        int percent = (int)(100.0*(double)progress[0]/mFileLen + 0.5);
        mDialog.setProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            showToast("Image successfully uploaded");
        } else {
            showToast(mErrorMsg);
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }
```

and MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Ashu";

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                      Your app-specific settings.                      //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Replace this with your app key and secret assigned by Dropbox.
    // Note that this is a really insecure way to do this, and you shouldn't
    // ship code which contains your key & secret in such an obvious way.
    // Obfuscation is good.
    final static private String APP_KEY = "";
    final static private String APP_SECRET = "";

    // If you'd like to change the access type to the full Dropbox instead of
    // an app folder, change this value.
    final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                      End app-specific settings.                       //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // You don't need to change these, leave them alone.
    final static private String ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    final static private String ACCESS_KEY_NAME = "ACCESS_KEY";
    final static private String ACCESS_SECRET_NAME = "ACCESS_SECRET";


    DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mApi;

    private boolean mLoggedIn;

    // Android widgets
    private Button mSubmit;
    private LinearLayout mDisplay;
    private Button mPhoto;
    private Button mRoulette;

    private ImageView mImage;

    private final String PHOTO_DIR = "/Photos/";

    final static private int NEW_PICTURE = 1;
    private String mCameraFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCameraFileName = savedInstanceState.getString("mCameraFileName");
        }

        // We create a new AuthSession so that we can use the Dropbox API.
        AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
        mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

        // Basic Android widgets
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        checkAppKeySetup();

        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.auth_button);

        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // This logs you out if you're logged in, or vice versa
                if (mLoggedIn) {
                    logOut();
                } else {
                    // Start the remote authentication
                    mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(MainActivity.this);
                }
            }
        });

        mDisplay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.logged_in_display);

        // This is where a photo is displayed
        mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        // This is the button to take a photo
        mPhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.photo_button);

        mPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
           //     Intent intent = new Intent();
                // Picture from camera
            //    intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                // This is not the right way to do this, but for some reason, having
                // it store it in
                // MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI isn't working right.

            //    Date date = new Date();
             //   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-kk-mm-ss");

          //      String newPicFile = df.format(date) + ".jpg";
            //    String outPath = "/sdcard/" + newPicFile;
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            //  String uniqueOutFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    //  .toString() + "/aa"+ ".mp4";



                File outFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/aa/ashu1.mp4");

                mCameraFileName = outFile.toString();


                UploadPicture upload = new UploadPicture(DBRoulette.this, mApi, PHOTO_DIR,outFile);
                upload.execute();


            }
        });


        // This is the button to take a photo
        mRoulette = (Button)findViewById(R.id.roulette_button);



        // Display the proper UI state if logged in or not
        setLoggedIn(mApi.getSession().isLinked());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("mCameraFileName", mCameraFileName);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AndroidAuthSession session = mApi.getSession();

        // The next part must be inserted in the onResume() method of the
        // activity from which session.startAuthentication() was called, so
        // that Dropbox authentication completes properly.
        if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // Mandatory call to complete the auth
                session.finishAuthentication();

                // Store it locally in our app for later use
                TokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
                storeKeys(tokens.key, tokens.secret);
                setLoggedIn(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                showToast("Couldn't authenticate with Dropbox:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.i(TAG, "Error authenticating", e);
            }
        }
    }

    // This is what gets called on finishing a media piece to import
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == NEW_PICTURE) {
            // return from file upload
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = null;
                if (data != null) {
                    uri = data.getData();
                }
                if (uri == null && mCameraFileName != null) {
                    uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFileName));
                }
                File file = new File(mCameraFileName);

                if (uri != null) {
                    UploadPicture upload = new UploadPicture(this, mApi, PHOTO_DIR, file);
                    upload.execute();
                }
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unknown Activity Result from mediaImport: "
                        + resultCode);
            }
        }
    }

    private void logOut() {
        // Remove credentials from the session
        mApi.getSession().unlink();

        // Clear our stored keys
        clearKeys();
        // Change UI state to display logged out version
        setLoggedIn(false);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience function to change UI state based on being logged in
     */
    private void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        mLoggedIn = loggedIn;
        if (loggedIn) {
            mSubmit.setText("Unlink from Dropbox");
            mDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mSubmit.setText("Link with Dropbox");
            mDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mImage.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    }

    private void checkAppKeySetup() {
        // Check to make sure that we have a valid app key
        if (APP_KEY.startsWith("CHANGE") ||
                APP_SECRET.startsWith("CHANGE")) {
            showToast("You must apply for an app key and secret from developers.dropbox.com, and add them to the  ap before trying it.");
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Check if the app has set up its manifest properly.
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String scheme = "db-" + APP_KEY;
        String uri = scheme + "://" + AuthActivity.AUTH_VERSION + "/test";
        testIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        if (0 == pm.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, 0).size()) {
            showToast("URL scheme in your app's " +
                    "manifest is not set up correctly. You should have a " +
                    "com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity with the " +
                    "scheme: " + scheme);
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }

    /**
     * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
     * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
     * time (which is not to be done, ever).
     *
     * @return Array of [access_key, access_secret], or null if none stored
     */
    private String[] getKeys() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
        String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
        if (key != null && secret != null) {
            String[] ret = new String[2];
            ret[0] = key;
            ret[1] = secret;
            return ret;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
     * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
     * time (which is not to be done, ever).
     */
    private void storeKeys(String key, String secret) {
        // Save the access key for later
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, key);
        edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, secret);
        edit.commit();
    }

    private void clearKeys() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.commit();
    }

    private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
        AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session;

        String[] stored = getKeys();
        if (stored != null) {
            AccessTokenPair accessToken = new AccessTokenPair(stored[0], stored[1]);
            session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE, accessToken);
        } else {
            session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE);
        }

        return session;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code we can see?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to directly upload a folder using the Dropbox SDK.  You'll need to enumerate the files yourself then upload them individually into a Dropbox folder which you create.  You can then share a link to that folder.